# How to avoid zombie processes? and what exactly init process does in this situation?

Tags: process, operating-system, zombie-process

How to avoid zombie processes?  and what exactly init process does in this situation? 
I've seen this program,but not able to get it:
 How does this program creates a zombie process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) 
{
    pid_t p = fork();

    if (p != 0) 
    {
        waitpid(p, NULL, 0); /* See if the child already had ended. */
        sleep(1); /* Wait 1 seconds for the child to end. And eat away the SIGCHLD in case if arrived. */
        pause(); /* Suspend main task. */
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(3); /* Just let the child live for some tme before becoming a zombie. */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to understand here? What problems are you having with your code?

Comment: code is okay.Its a working code taken from some reference. Just wanted  its explaination ..  That how this creates a zombie process .

Comment: Init has nothing to do in this situation. When a process terminates before waiting on the return status of its spawned children, the created processes become `zombie processes` after terminiating, until init `waits`. 

In your case, the parent process waits. So init has nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

A child process turns into a zombie process when it did exit but the parent process did not yet run `waitpid`, `wait` or `waitid` on it. In a normal situation a parent would want to know the exit status on the child process it spawned and therefore woud run [waitpid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) on the pid it got from `fork`.

What happens in your code above:

- the child is spawned and exits (leaves the else clause and returns 0)
- the parent runs into the endless `pause` loop until you press ctrl-c (the sleep and waitpid are superflous)

If you start the program and leave it running (`./a.out &`) and then run `ps -fx` then you see something like this:

```
 6940 pts/1    SN     0:00      ./a.out
 6943 pts/1    ZN     0:00       \_ [a.out] <defunct>
```

Now, if you kill the parent process (`kill 6940`) then the child becomes an orphan and the init process automatically becomes the new parent. Since the init process runs `waitpid` (aka "reaps" the child) on all processes it inherits the zombie process finally is deleted from the process table and does not show up any more via `ps -f`